# Why does this work in Dreamweaver 'live' but not browser?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, dreamweaver

I have a sidebar menu that I'm trying to get to slide up and out of sight when one of the menu items, blog, is clicked.  Like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4m2cf0a/). It shows up fine in dreamweaver live preview, but not in the browser.
HEre is my html:

```
<div id="sidebar"> 
        <div id="navigation">
          <div id="logo">
          <img src="Logos/headerlogo.jpg" width="208" height="80" longdesc="Logos/headerlogo.jpg">
        </div>
    <hr size=1 width=179 align=left style="margin-left:17px; margin-bottom:20px">
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="first" >
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Blog</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Instagram</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">About</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Store</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.first .blog').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar').animate({
        "marginTop": "-=500px"       //animate margin to create slide up animation  
    }, 1000);                        //duration of animation, in milliseconds
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: it just works fine.What is the issue??

Comment: Your fiddle is not the same as your included code. Which one is up-to-date?

Comment: My problem is that it works fine in fiddle and dreamweaver preview, but not an actual internet browser. Not sure why

Comment: Only the logo is different in the fiddle, just to show an image. But the fiddle is uptodate

Comment: Did you forget to link to a hosted jQuery library somewhere? And your JavaScript is different; there isn't as much/the same in your linked Fiddle. It's good practice to use the exact same code in your Fiddle as you post here, to avoid confusion.

Comment: that might be it! I haven't hosted it yet. And you're right, the javascript in the posted code is correct, but in the fiddle is old. I'll try hosting it

Comment: If you are linking to the google hosted jquery library, or even the jquery CDN, previewing your page locally will not work.  In order for it to work when loaded locally, ALL resources have to be loaded locally.  Downloading jquery.js and including it locally will fix your previews when loading locally.  I would however suggest sticking with googles hosted library when you host the site live, as you have a greater chance of that file being cached already.

Comment: what browser are you using? If Internet Explorer, try Compatibility View Settings.